# If I update a SQL table Scheme. Do I have to update all users DBs linked tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, odbc

I updated the SCHEMA of a live table in MySQL for use in my multi-user database. Each user has their own db and links to the production tables through ODBC.

I have been receiving a write error while trying to test my schema updates. I cannot find the core reason. I hypothesized that because the other users are in the production table but have not been relinked to update the table SCHEMA; That it is causing a conflicting write error on my relinked table.

I added a TINYINT with No NULLS and default value of 0

I double checked all datatypes for incompatibility & have tested the "non relinked" tables in a older version of the DB and confirmed it is working as intended with no errors

I expect/want to be able to edit records without a write error, but am hesitant to update the other users to the new table if it is currently having write errors

Comment: can you explain `links to the production tables through ODBC` more?

Comment: Im using mysql to host the database, then linking the access database to the mysql tables through ODBC

Answer (score 2):

After changing the schema of a linked table, it's required to refresh the link on all Access databases connected to it.

You can do this on the ribbon through external data -> linked table manager.

Unfortunately, either all users that have a database need to do this manually, unless you automate the task on startup through vba.

Comment: Do you know if all users HAVE to? I don't need anyone but me to have the updated tables while i work on the upgrades to the front end. However I cant seem to make any edits while they are in the tables that have yet to be relinked.

Comment: That's what a development server/environment is for. When ready and tested, copy the changes to the production environment.

Comment: All users have to. For a proven method for distributing updated frontends, study my article: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
I will soon be implementing a development environment into the system after dealing with this issue. I happen to be taking over someone elses system while learning as I go

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate issues. To "see" new columns, then yes, you must re-link the tables.
(so above is separate question and separate issue). You thus as a general rule can add new columns to the database (even while in use). However, the client side linked tables will not see the new columns until such time you re-link. This approach (adding new columns, but not yet re-linked from Access) is certainly ok and fine - the only downside is end users can't see nor use the new columns until such time you link. From a developer point of view, this good - since your users will not see nor find new columns until such time you roll out a new front end to each work station.

Ok, now problem and issue number two.

As for adding a new column, then re-linking, and THEN having some issue is really a separate issue. In most cases, if you attempting to use a tiny int as a Boolean (and I think that is your case), then you need to ensure several things:

Do not allow nulls (you seem to have this ok).
Make sure you set a default of 0 (server side) for this column. (you might have not allowed nulls, but without a default, then Access likely will still complain. And this default is important during creating time - since the new column needs to be "filled" with zeros. 
Make sure the table has a PK defined.

Consider adding a row version column (I think mySQL has these, not sure but they can help immensely).

Comment: I have double checked the TINYINT(boolean) is set to no nulls & defaults to 0

I also went ahead and ran a Update SET booleancolumn = 0 on all rows to triple check.

Also, we have a timestamp field in the table as well